# realizing the better method through statistical scores

Tags: c#, .net, excel, math, statistics

I have 7000 data instances.

I have those instances manually scored by a human (The reference).

I have different Engines to determine the data's score automatically.

I have an excel sheet who's each column describes a certain engine's score and one column of the manually scored data.

I want to know which of the engines is the closer to the human's scoring using either Excel's functions , programming, or just give me the simple maths of it and I'll work it out.

Data scoring is from -3.0 to +3.0

I use C# for that application and .NET Excel COM libraries to access the excel sheet.

-UPDATE-

Statistically speaking, what's the best way to describe the error, I mean the human score tend to be close to neutral (0) , but the Engines' scores tends to be biased (above 1.5 +/-) I want to be able to determine the best equation to describe and exaggerate the error in a right way.

Comment: @Mranz 
"I want to know which of the engines is the closer to the human's scoring...."

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham 
The usual, just taking the average of each engine's score, and ordered them by the closer to farther  to/from the manual score.

Comment: You might want to try this question on [stats.se] as it seems to me to be more about statistical analysis than programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a mean squared error. For each data instance calculate the square of the difference for each engine. This will exaggerate the error, and give positive numbers. Then you take the average squared error for each engine. The lowest would be the "closest" estimator to the human.

Comment: average squared error you mean (sum of all +7000 squared error/+7000) ??

Answer (score 1):

Typically done by subtracting the engine score from the human score, taking the absolute value, then summing all 7000.  The engine with the smallest sum is the closest.

Comment: That's one way to do it, although not necessarily the best. For example, Engine 1 might have differences that are scattered all over, but its overall average is slightly better than Engine 2 whose differences are always within a few percent of the human's score. Which of the two is better?

Answer (score 1):

The [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance%5C) between the data sets should be good enough if every data point is in the same range. For clarity, data instances will be numbered, and engines will be lettered. If the score given by the human on data point `i` is `H_i`, and the score given by engine `a` is `Ea_i`, then the error (how "not close" a given engine is) for engine `a` is:

```
ERROR(a) = (H_1 - Ea_1)^2 + (H_2 - Ea_2)^2 + … + (H_7000 - Ea_7000)^2
```

The closest engine is the engine for which the error is smallest.